# How do I suppress scientific notation in python when I read hexadecimal string from excel by pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read hexadecimal string (like User ID) as file name from excel files by pandas
But default type in pandas is float, so when I read those columns (which contains the number and 'e') from the file, those ID will be scientific notation like 9645e101 --> 9.645e+104.

I have tried

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')
sheet=xls.parse(sheetname,convert_float=False)
```

and

```
sheet['ID'].astype('str')
```

both solutions didn't work for me
string came out still in scientific notation
does there exists a way to suppress converting to scientific notation? Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Hi, you can use this `np.printoptions(suppress=True)`

Comment: I have tried this solution but it's not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give the explicit dtypes of the columns as a dictionary indexed by the column names:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')
sheet = xls.parse(sheetname, dtype={'ID': 'str'})
```

It could even be possible with no header line

```
sheet = xls.parse(sheetname, header=None, dtype={0: 'str'})
```